# Running 3 Month Count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get a list of new accounts twice a month. Majority of my accounts have either gone through the funnel or can be categorized as a bad lead by the end of the third month. So I am working on sql query that will tell me the number of accounts in my funnel at each date when I received a new list.

Here is what I have been working with (Yes I joined table1 on itself):

```
select t.receiveddate, count(*)
from table1 t
join table1 t2 on t2.number = t.number 
and (t2.receiveddate > Dateadd(month , -3, t.received) AND t2.receiveddate<= 
t.receiveddate)
group by t.receiveddate
```

What I am hoping to end up with is a list of the dates that I receive new business, with a count of how many accounts are in the funnel (accounts that I received no more than 3 months ago). The count should include the new accounts received on that date as well.

Here is an example, lets assume the business started on 1/1/2000, there is no one in the funnel for the first count. Lets also assume that I get 100 new accounts every time, just to make things simple for this example.

```
  receiveddate    Count
   1/1/2000        100
   1/15/2000       200
   2/1/2000        300
   2/15/2000       300
   3/1/2000        300
   3/15/2000       300
```

Comment: So what's the question???

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is field [number]?

Comment: If you get 100 twice per month, shouldn't your results read: 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 600, 600, 600 ...

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear. I am trying to get a 3 month running count.
David, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

I see where you were going with that, but I would use a correlated sub-query, instead.  I've included my sample data, which I randomized to make it similar to the real world - you can use an `Update` statement to change them all to 100 to validate the query):

```
create table Pipeline
(
    ID int identity
    , Received_Date Date
    , Received_Count Int
)

Insert Into Pipeline
select '01/01/2018', 75 + (RAND() * 50)
union all select '01/15/2018', 75 + (RAND() * 50)
union all select '02/01/2018', 75 + (RAND() * 50)
union all select '02/15/2018', 75 + (RAND() * 50)
union all select '03/01/2018', 75 + (RAND() * 50)
union all select '03/15/2018', 75 + (RAND() * 50)
union all select '04/01/2018', 75 + (RAND() * 50)
union all select '04/15/2018', 75 + (RAND() * 50)
union all select '05/01/2018', 75 + (RAND() * 50)
union all select '05/15/2018', 75 + (RAND() * 50)
union all select '06/01/2018', 75 + (RAND() * 50)
union all select '06/15/2018', 75 + (RAND() * 50)


select * from Pipeline        -- so you can see the values you got

select 
    P1.Received_Date
    , (Select Sum(P2.Received_Count)
        from Pipeline as P2
        Where P2.Received_Date > DateAdd(MONTH, -3, P1.Received_Date) 
        and P2.Received_Date <= P1.Received_Date
        ) As Pipeline_Total
from Pipeline as P1
```

Comment: This is perfect!

Comment: Glad I could help.  It was an interesting problem.

Comment: This worked great but I want to add one more thing. Each account has a Lead Score between 1 and 5. If I wanted to know the number of accounts in my funnel for each lead score (last 3 months still), how would I go about doing that?

Comment: so instead of 100 accounts, you have (for example) 40 accounts with a lead score of 1, 40 accounts with a lead score of 3, and 20 accounts with a lead score of 4?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I have.

Comment: Odd - I thought I posted this already.  I would add a column for Lead Score and have five sub-queries - Pipeline_Total_One, etc - and add Lead Score to the `Where` clause in each.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear.  I assume that you have a table of accounts, and for each account you have the received-date.

```
-- One record per account, each with a received-date

create table Account ( AccountID int identity(1,1), 
                       ReceivedDate date )

-- Populate with 1000 random received-dates.
-- DateAdd(month,... gives a range of 60 months
-- DateAdd(day,...   forces either 1st or 15th of the month
-- Of course, the query below will work regardless of the
-- distribution of dates

declare @k int
set @k = 0
while @k < 1000
  begin

     insert into Account ( ReceivedDate ) values
     ( DateAdd ( day,   14*cast( 2*rand()as int), 
       DateAdd ( month,    cast(60*rand()as int), '2000-01-01' ) ) )

     set @k = @k + 1
  end

-- Let's see the list of dates
select * from Account

-- T1 is the list of DISTINCT received-dates
-- Other than that this query almost matches your own attempt

select T1.ReceivedDate, count(*) as InFunnel
from 
  (select distinct ReceivedDate from Account) T1, 
  Account T2
where     T2.ReceivedDate > DateAdd ( month, -3, T1.ReceivedDate )
      and T2.ReceivedDate <= T1.ReceivedDate 
group by T1.ReceivedDate
order by T1.ReceivedDate
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!